# Change XML element name using XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am trying to change XML node name but it doesn't allow me to do so. In my below code I I have two templates 1. Change Node name 2.Create parent node for DocumentReference. Please see my XML and XSLT.

My XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <DataArea>
    <PurchaseOrder>
        <PurchaseOrderLine>
            <DocumentReference>
                <DocumentID>
                    <ID>23423</ID>
                </DocumentID>
            </DocumentReference>
            <DocumentReference>
                <DocumentID>
                    <ID>23424</ID>
                </DocumentID>
            </DocumentReference>
            <Item>
                <CustomerItemID>
                    <!-- ArtNr -->
                    <ID>444</ID>
                </CustomerItemID>
            </Item>
            <Quantity unitCode="PCE">17.3</Quantity>
        </PurchaseOrderLine>
    </PurchaseOrder>
  </DataArea>
```

Expected Result

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <DataArea>
    <PurchaseOrder>
        <POL>
            <DocumentReference>
                <DocumentID>
                    <ID>23423</ID>
                </DocumentID>
            </DocumentReference>
            <DocumentReference>
                <DocumentID>
                    <ID>23424</ID>
                </DocumentID>
            </DocumentReference>
            <Item>
                <CustomerItemID>
                    <!-- ArtNr -->
                    <ID>444</ID>
                </CustomerItemID>
            </Item>
            <Quantity unitCode="PCE">17.3</Quantity>
        </POL>
    </PurchaseOrder>
  </DataArea>
```

My XSLT

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>   

   <xsl:template match="PurchaseOrderLine">
      <POL>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </POL>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="PurchaseOrderLine">
        <xsl:copy>
        <Kiran>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|DocumentReference"/>
        </Kiran>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|Item|Quantity"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>   

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can't have two templates with `match="PurchaseOrderLine"`. And you can't create attributes once you have created a child node.

Comment: How can perform both the task in order to achieve goal? Any suggestion

Comment: In one template you have a literal result element `Kiran` which I do not see anywhere in your wanted result so it is hard to tell what you want to achieve. Please clarify.

Comment: I have two objectives 1. Rename PurchaseOrderLine to POL 2. Add new parent tag Kiran only for DocumentReference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then I think you want the template to look like

```
<xsl:template match="PurchaseOrderLine"> 
  <POL> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <Kiran>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="DocumentReference"/>
    </Kiran>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except DocumentReference" />
  </POL> 
</xsl:template>
```