# change xml property(element) name dynmically while serialization

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb

I am creating an xml feed from java pojo's using jaxb. My requirement is to change the name of elements in xml feed dynamically based on some logic. For example i have below feed created from jaxb:

```
<Customer>
   <ClientId>123</ClientId>
   <ClientName>ABC</ClientName>
</Customer>
```

Now before sending to Client A i want xml feed as:

```
<Customer>
   <Id>123</Id>
   <ClientName>ABC</ClientName>
</Customer>
```

For other client it could be

```
<Customer>
   <Identifier>123</Identifier>
   <ClientName>ABC</ClientName>
</Customer>
```

Is there a way to change xml elements name dynamically in Jaxb or any other solution? I have to do same thing for json output also.

Thanks,
Suraj

Comment: have you tried something already? which is the logic to change `id` but not `name` ?

Comment: Using XSLT? See here for starters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871731/change-xml-element-name-using-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using an XSLT. 
In this example I used your

```
<Customer>
   <ClientId>123</ClientId>
   <ClientName>ABC</ClientName>
</Customer>
```

and transformed it to

```
<Customer>
   <Id>123</Id>
   <ClientName>ABC</ClientName>
</Customer>
```

The XSLT will match all `ClientId` nodes and rename them to `Id`

```
public class XmlTransform
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, TransformerException
  {
    String inXMl = "<Customer>\n" +
            "   <ClientId>123</ClientId>\n" +
            "   <ClientName>ABC</ClientName>\n" +
            "</Customer>";

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    String inputXSLFile = "d:\\rename.xslt";

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource(new File(inputXSLFile));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslStream);

    StreamSource in = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inXMl));
    StreamResult out = new StreamResult(writer);
    transformer.transform(in, out);
    System.out.println(writer.toString());
  }
}
```

**The XSLT File**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:business="mynamespace.uri"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ClientId">
    <xsl:element name="Id">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```