# XML mapping using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to change an input xml file to a given format.

My input xml is:

```
 <Syncaaa xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/ Syncaaa.xsd" releaseID="9.2" versionID="2.0.1">
        <eee>
            <Sender>
                <BOD>qwqqs</BOD>
                <ID>1222</ID>
                <Code>Success</Code>
            </Sender>
        </eee>
        <ddd>
            <bbb>
                <EntityId>100</EntityId>
            </bbb>
            <aaa type="xoxo">
                <Item>
                    <Status>true</Status>
                    <zzzz>O</zzzz>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <Status>false</Status>
                    <zzzz>1</zzzz>
                </Item>
            </aaa>
        </ddd>
    </Syncaaa>
```

From above xml, I want to extract below xml part.

```
<aaa type="xoxo">
    <Item>
        <Status>true</Status>
        <zzzz>O</zzzz>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Status>false</Status>
        <zzzz>1</zzzz>
    </Item>
</aaa>
```

And, tag names of the extracted xml should be changed as below.

- `<ddd>` -> `<Updatedaaa>`
- `<Item>` -> `<UpdateItem>`
- `<Status>` -> `<UpdatedStatus>`
- `<zzzz>` -> `<Updatedzzzz>`

Excepted output is like below.

```
<Updatedaaa>
            <UpdateItem>
                <UpdatedStatus>true</UpdatedStatus>
                <Updatedzzzz>0</Updatedzzzz>
            </UpdateItem>
            <UpdateItem>
                <UpdatedStatus>false</UpdatedStatus>
                <Updatedzzzz>1</Updatedzzzz>
            </UpdateItem>
        </Updatedaaa>
```

I tried to do that task using below xsl file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ddd"> 
  <UpdatedItem> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <UpdatedStatus>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Status"/>
    </UpdatedStatus>
    <Updatedzzzz>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="zzzz"/>
    </Updatedzzzz>
  </UpdatedItem> 
</xsl:template>


  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it didn't work with this xsl file. Please help me to identify the issue.

Thanks,

Comment: yes you can do this,are you using any developer tool?

Comment: No, I just try on online tools. And, I tried to do this using some another SO questions. like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871731/change-xml-element-name-using-xslt

Comment: Your question does not contain any XSLT code. Please make an attempt and describe where you are stuck.

Comment: Updated the question with XSLT code.

Comment: Start here, then work on your other issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758492/xslt-transform-doesnt-work-until-i-remove-root-node/34762628#34762628

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a namespace associated in the input XML `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"` which is missing in the XSL. Need to add the following in the XSL to use the namespace.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="html">
```

The XML data can then be accessed by adding the namespace prefix to the XML nodes. There can be multiple solutions to get the desired output, like the one below.

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="html">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Updatedaaa>
            <xsl:for-each select="//*/html:Item">
                <UpdatedItem>
                    <UpdatedStatus>
                        <xsl:value-of select="html:Status" />
                    </UpdatedStatus>
                    <Updatedzzzz>
                        <xsl:value-of select="html:zzzz" />
                    </Updatedzzzz>
                </UpdatedItem>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Updatedaaa>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT when applied to the input XML shared produces the desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Updatedaaa>
    <UpdatedItem>
        <UpdatedStatus>true</UpdatedStatus>
        <Updatedzzzz>O</Updatedzzzz>
    </UpdatedItem>
    <UpdatedItem>
        <UpdatedStatus>false</UpdatedStatus>
        <Updatedzzzz>1</Updatedzzzz>
    </UpdatedItem>
</Updatedaaa>
```